# Computing weakly/daily mean in multiple time-series inside data table

Tags: r, csv, time-series

I am quite new to R and I am having some problems with performing some more complex operations with `data.table`. I am not sure if it even could be done so I would be glad for any help.

First of all, let me describe my problem and the desired goal on a simplified sample data:

```
type     region     quantity     timestamp
small     A            2         05/01/15 10:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 10:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 10:00
big       A            1         05/01/15 10:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 11:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 11:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 12:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 12:00
small     B            4         05/01/15 12:00
big       A            1         05/01/15 12:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 13:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 13:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 13:00
big       A            1         05/01/15 13:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 14:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 14:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 14:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 14:00
small     B            2         05/01/15 14:00
big       A            1         05/01/15 14:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 15:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 15:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 15:00
big       A            1         05/01/15 15:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 16:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 16:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 16:00
small     A            3         05/01/15 16:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 16:00
big       A            1         05/01/15 16:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 17:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 17:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 17:00
big       A            1         05/01/15 17:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 18:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 18:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 18:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 18:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 18:00
big       A            1         05/01/15 18:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 19:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 19:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 19:00
big       B            1         05/01/15 19:00
small     B            2         05/01/15 20:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 20:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 20:00
small     A            1         05/01/15 20:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 20:00
big       A            1         05/01/15 20:00
small     A            2         05/01/15 21:00
small     A            3         05/01/15 22:00
small     B            1         05/01/15 23:00
big       A            1         06/01/15 00:00
small     A            2         06/01/15 00:00
small     B            1         06/01/15 00:00
small     A            1         06/01/15 01:00
small     A            1         06/01/15 01:00
small     B            1         06/01/15 01:00
big       A            1         06/01/15 01:00
big       A            1         06/01/15 02:00
small     A            2         06/01/15 02:00
small     B            1         06/01/15 02:00
small     A            1         06/01/15 03:00
big       A            1         06/01/15 04:00
big       A            1         06/01/15 04:00
small     A            2         06/01/15 04:00
small     B            1         06/01/15 04:00
small     A            1         06/01/15 05:00
small     A            1         06/01/15 05:00
small     B            1         06/01/15 05:00
big       A            1         06/01/15 05:00
```

What I need to do is to produce weakly means (of total amount of quantity) for each unique combination of type and region.

That means for example:

```
weak1 (05/01/15 00:00 - 12/01/15 00:00): 50 hours of 'small' in region 'A'
...
```

Each unique combination of the type and region must be treated separately. In order to do that, I think I need to do the following steps:

```
1. Load the csv
2. Aggregate all the rows with same combinations together (there could be duplicate rows with different quantities)
3. Compute the weakly means or sums for each unique combination
4. Save the results into multiple csv files (one file per unique combination)
```

This is my code so far, I am really stuck on step 3 and 4. If someone could suggest how such thing could be done, it would be really helpful.

```
# parse CSV
library(data.table)
DF <- read.table(file="data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",check.names=FALSE)

# aggregate same values together
DT <- data.table(DF)
aggregated <- DT[, .(quant = sum(quantity)), by = .(timestamp, region, type)]

print(aggregated)
```

EDIT: I added some more data to the example. For the sake of understanding how this is done (and avoiding posting thousands rows of data here), it is enough to compute just the daily means. I am sure that converting this to weakly means will be easy.

EDIT2: If the combination exists at least once in the dataset, I need to to display the weakly outcome even it it's 0. Is there a way how to insert zero values to the periods of time when there is no record?

Comment: It would be nice if your example data had more than one day so we could test the results. Adding expected output also helps.

Comment: I will try to come up with some better example data set. I wanted to avoid posting 1000 rows of data here since it would make the question very  confusing. I assume that computing, for example, daily means works in similar matter so I will post two or three days of data here to test this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I don't work with data.tables normally. Usually it's dataframe and ddply for me. But assuming that your data.table aggregation works, the code snippet below should do the trick...

```
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT$date<-as.Date(DT$timestamp)
aggregated <- DT[, .(quant = mean(quantity)), by = .(date, region, type)]
```

EDIT:

For weekly:

```
library(ISOweek)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT$date<-as.Date(DT$timestamp)
DT$week<-ISOweek(DT$date)
aggregated <- DT[, .(quant = mean(quantity)), by = .(week, region, type)]
```

Comment: Thats true - this converts all the timestamps to dates (and hence crop the hour and minute data from it) so I can aggregate by days. This does, however, not solve how to scale this approach for weakly means...

Comment: If you want weekly, take the package `ISOweek`. See edit above. BTW, please accept the answer. If that's what you are looking for...

Comment: Wow, this week grouping works surprisingly nicely. I did not know about this ISOweek packages, thanks! DO you, by any chance know, how to save this data.table into multiple ones? I need to have a separate file for every combination of region and type